# How to draw a smooth circle SKphysicsbody in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Everytime I try to use `node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: node.size.width/2)` it draws a polygon instead of a smooth circle. How can I make the physics body have more edges and appear more smooth?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the polygon is just a visual representation of physics body (for drawing speed purposes), and the actual body is a circle.

Comment: When you say draw, do you mean that you have showsPhysics enabled?